# is it possible that packet loss could be causing VoIP software to fail?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, voip, packet-loss

We've been using a VoIP software and it's been failing to receive calls and sometimes it hangs up on customers face.

The software tech support used MTR and showed us that our ISP is using a route that has a hop with packet loss and this would be the cause to the problem. Does that make sense though?

Meanwhile, I've installed VPN on machines that requires the VoIP and it seems to solve the problem, since each VPN IP has routes with no packet loss.

Comment: I think that you have answered your own question.

Comment: Indeed, of course it makes sense. If the connection doesn't fully go through, the call will not come in/fail.

Comment: @jsotola your comment doesn't help, at all.

Comment: @harrymc I said "it seems to solve", which implies I'm no sure if it did and why.

Comment: @YisroelTech read davidgo answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no! Its possible, but unlikely the issue here.

Packet loss CAN cause failures, but this almost certainly not the case here.

A few things to unpack first -

1. VOIP typically uses UDP which is "fire and forget".  There is enough built into most protocols to handle a fair bit of packet loss without the issues you describe.  **You will notice voice quality problems way before difficulty with call management.**
2. MTR is brilliant, but needs to be interpreted in context and bearing in mind its limits.  Packet loss on a single hop usually is a non-issue as it will be the router deprioritising packets handled on that router.  Provided subsequent hops don't show packet loss ypu can discount that packet loss here.
3. If a VPN solves the problem its highly likely your connection is not bandwidth constrained (but it is possible).

What is likely happening is you are behind CGN, or even normal NAT and your router is not intelligent enough to manage the VOIP packets.  I'm guessing your devices are using the SIP protocol, and the SIP protocol does not play well with NAT.   A VPN can fix this problem.  (SIP typically tries to establish a connection to the "PABX" and then handshake connections directly between the end devices which is where NAT becomes an issue.  Googling "SIP NAT issues" will describe this at different technical levels if you want to get more into the weeds.

Comment: Thanks for answering and not being condescending. I've read your answer and it will help me finding the root cause. I've learnt a lot from you answer, already.